# VBA : While loop not working with multiple (or) condtions

Tags: vba, loops, while-loop

```
Sub Demo()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

x = 20
y = 15

While ((x <> 10) Or (y <> 10))
    x = x - 1
    y = y - 1
    Debug.Print x & " : " & y
    Wend

Debug.Print x & " : " & y
End Sub
```

This loop goes in infinte mode, instead of breaking at conditions, when x or y become equal to 10. I tried using `Do..While..Loop`, but even that doesn't work. Can't we use multiple condtions with `While` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `or` with `and`!

Even if x is 10, y is not equal 10 and vice versa, therefore your condition is always true and your loop will go on forever...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the logic used from "OR" to "AND".

Everytime it iterates currently, it's checking either of the things are true, however, if y = 10, and X does not, you will continue looping as it evaluates both.

With "AND", as soon as one condition is met your loop breaks.